Azure B2C custom policy forgot password not working properly
I have setup a custom policy with a Identity provider discovery based on this. And set up the 'base' policies using this tool with 'Remove Facebook references' and 'Enable JavaScript' enabled.
The policy for work when signing in with users from local or other identity providers. The issue I am having is that the password reset link isn't triggering a flow for password reset and where it redirects me, I can't reset the password there.(it redirects me here)

What I want is to either hide link, or have a password reset flow that work(for local users only).
I tried to hide it with
<Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkLocation">None</Item> 

but that seems to do nothing.
I've tried to make a working flow by creating a subJourney for reset based on this, but is is not triggering.

It looks like your external IDP is Entra ID, and you are trying to trigger the password reset on the Entra ID screen as an Entra ID user.
Does a password reset with a local account work?
That sample only allows local logins if the domain is not in the configured list.

No, it doesn't work. The link from the 'Forgot my password' goes to 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/[tenantId]/oauth2/authorize?client_id=[clientID]&redirect_uri=[redirectUri]&response_type=id_token&scope=openid&response_mode=form_post&nonce=...&sso_reload=true#' and if I do the steps from there I get the error "SSPR_0010: Your organization hasn’t turned on password writeback."
But I don't want it to go like that in any case, I would expect the 'Forgot my password' link to redirect me to a SubJourney I created for PasswordReset described above.

This is an Entra ID error not a B2C error. What email address are you logging in with? What does your domain table look like?

Indeed, but I don't even want to get to that point. What I want is that when I press the 'Forgot my password' button to be redirected to a passwordReset subJourney or to hide the 'forgot my password' button

What I think is happening is that your domain lookup table is wrong, so you are following the social route rather than the local route, which is why the local reset flow is never triggered.
